# Import many independent PDF files to Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, automation, import

Is the a way to easy import many **independent PDF** files automatically to Photoshop?

Now i move all files to PS and must confirm each of file like this
:
https://gyazo.com/0884a4827b506a6c1a66785b893c3f11

Answer (score 2):

`File > Scripts > Load files into Stack`..

[image]

Select the files or a folder containing the files and sit back and wait...

Photoshop will open each PDF, copy it, and combine them all into a single document, one layer per file.

Comment: Good solution if all your PDFs have the same size and only contain one page.

Comment: @Wolff .. yup.. I watched the link....

Answer (score 1):

- Open Adobe Acrobat Pro.
- Select *File > Create > Combine Files into a Single PDF*.
- Click *Add Files* and choose all your PDFs.
- Click *Combine*.
- Save the file.
- Drag the new combined PDF into Photoshop.
- To select all pages, click the first page, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the last page.
- Click *OK*.